# C# Loop For Searching Character Not Working

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, indexing

I have a loop searching for the index of the user enterted character converter to a char array compared to the secret word, and while it does loop over it for how long the word is it still isn't going to my messagebox (which is for debugging to check if its worked). I also don't know how to reveal a letter.

```
private void guessBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] randomCharArray = randomInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
    char[] userInputArray = userInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < randomCharArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (randomCharArray[i] == userInputArray[i])
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        }
    }
}

private void resetGamebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetUpWords();
}

private void SetUpWords()
{
    string path = (@"C:\commonwords.txt"); // Save the variable path with the path to the txt file
    words = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    int guessIndex = (new Random()).Next(words.Length);
    currentWord = words[guessIndex];

    for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.Length; i++)
    {
        wordlbl.Text += "*";
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly related: First check should be for equal lengths ...

Comment: Did you step it through in a debugger? I guess the values are not what you think they are.

Comment: Stepping through it yes the random char array value in the for loop is char[0] same for userInputArray and value of i remains zero also need to figre a way of when clicking reset to run the SetupWords method to only run it once, when I click it it loads new words and keeps adding * to it
https://codepaste.net/s9r28n 
Now get a index out of range exception at userInputArray[i] in the if statements

Comment: One question at a time, Liam. _"value of i remains zero"_ - does it even enter the loop? Check randomCharArray.Length - is it 0 ?

Comment: It is 0 like i said sadly it does enter it now but I get and index out of range

Comment: Yes because you check something completely different for the length ("CurrentWord"). So I guess `randomInput` is not properly initialized with the value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If randomInput and userInput are textbox, you forgot .Text to get a String value.

Try this :

```
char[] randomCharArray = randomInput.Text.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
char[] userInputArray = userInput.Text.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
```

instead of this :

```
char[] randomCharArray = randomInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
char[] userInputArray = userInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
```

Edit after given more info in comment :

The out of index exception is due to the fact that randomCharArray is greater than userInputChar.

2 potentials solution :

```
    private void guessBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char[] randomCharArray = randomInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
        char[] userInputArray = userInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
        //Assume that userInput would never be superior than randomCharArray
        //And contain only one char
        for (int i = 0; i < randomCharArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (randomCharArray[i] == userInputArray[0])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hi");
            }
        }
       // Clean userInput in form
       userInputBox.Text = "";
    }
```

And

```
    private void guessBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] randomCharArray = randomInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
    char[] userInputArray = userInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
    // userInput can be equal to randomCharArray but running is more longer

    for (int i = 0; i < randomCharArray.Length; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < userInputArray.Length; j++){
        if (randomCharArray[i] == userInputArray[j])
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a red underline with an error saying "String does not contain a definition for Text and no extension Method text accepting a first argument of type string could be found
EDIT: Fixed as only userInputArray was from a textbox 
EDIT: Still index out of range but lengh does return the lengh of the current word but i still remains 0 and gets index out of range at this line
 if (randomCharArray[i] == userInputArray[i])

Comment: EDIT: Still index out of range but lengh does return the lengh of the current word but i does increase to one till it hits that if statement

Comment: As I say, is only ok, if userInput or randomInput are Textbox.
Debug over userinput, check if it is correctly initialized and if value are set.

Comment: Your right randomCharArray does get a value, but there is no user input going through. I.e the letter value is not setting

Comment: Check on your form for the name of the Textbox used for userInput ? 
Tips to fast debug , add => if(userInputArray == null || userInputArray.Length == 0){ //display some info}

Comment: The name of the textbox is userInputBox the if statement stops it from going to the one that gives it in an index out of range and the i increaements

Comment: char[] userInputArray = userInputBox.Text.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray(); => test like that just to be sure in this case you get the user value

Comment: From debugging in the locals userInput array has char[1] in itas a value checking it it is the value "v" which is what I entered

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < randomCharArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (randomCharArray[i] == userInputArray[i])
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        }
    }`
randomInputArray is always greater than userInputArray, so when you pass to 1 userInputArray have no other index because it have only one value stored...

Comment: What should I do? I've fixed when resetting the game the wordLabel returns to  string.Empty so its more clean. Just gotta get it to compare the input

Comment: I will edit my answer later with a possible solution, it would be more clear

Comment: Okay cheers, currentWord.Contains(userGuess)) works but now I need to reveal the letter so maybe that's not the way

Comment: Answer Edited ;)

Comment: Thanks, using the debugger I've got the currentWord but sadly the message box never pops up I know the letters are correct

Comment: I edited and the input is going through but sadly doesn't show Hi

Comment: You can use .Equals (return a bool) 

`if(randomCharArray[i].Equals(userInputArray[0]){ // Do something }`

Comment: Ok nice one, I edited the randomCharArray to currentWord and the .Equals now works, nice one. Any idea how to reveal the correct character and the right index? Though I got an index out of range but don't now.

Comment: Ok fixed out of bounds error, do you know how to reveal a character at the current index I'm sure its obvious but as you can tell I'm not that good with for loops and indexes

Comment: Prefer to check length ... Like that if(a.Length > b.Length).

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: I found the cause  of index out of range, it's when I generate a word and make an empty guess
if (randomCharArray[i].Equals(userInputArray[0]))
Is the cause

Comment: I've put in so the label updates the text score when it gets a letter right but it's only doing the first letter and I can keep entering it for the score to go up. I need to somehow keep an array of entered letters and compare don't know how I would do that. But dont know how to fix the score error:
https://codepaste.net/1cbps6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155806/discussion-between-echozulu-and-liam-vallance).